# Git github set user avatar with base64 favicon

Tags: git, github, base64, favicon, gravatar

I need to set up a user's avatar on github which is a bot that is activated via action with a base64 favicon.

This base64 favicon is taken from the reference site, I did a test with Google.

The favicon is taken correctly but is not set as the user's avatar.

In the end I tried to remove both the file containing the bas64 of the image and the favicon, I also tried not to remove them thinking that it could be the problem, but it still doesn't work.

Is the only possible solution to use gravatar?

Can you give me a hand?

```
curl -s www.google.com/favicon.ico > favicon.ico
base64 favicon.ico > favicon_base64.txt
AVATAR_BASE64=$(cat favicon_base64.txt)

# Initialize git
remote_repo="https://${GITHUB_ACTOR}:${GITHUB_TOKEN}@github.com/${GITHUB_REPOSITORY}.git"
git config http.sslVerify "${SSL_VERIFY}"
git config user.avatar "data:image/png;base64,${AVATAR_BASE64}"
git config user.name "${NAME}"
git config user.email "${EMAIL}"
git remote add publisher "${remote_repo}"
git show-ref # Useful for debugging
git branch --verbose

$(rm favicon_base64.txt favicon.ico)
```

or

```
curl -s "www.google.com/favicon.ico" --output favicon.ico

if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "Error: Failed to download the favicon."
    exit 1
fi

AVATAR_BASE64=$(base64 favicon.ico)

# Initialize git
remote_repo="https://${GITHUB_ACTOR}:${GITHUB_TOKEN}@github.com/${GITHUB_REPOSITORY}.git"
git config http.sslVerify "${SSL_VERIFY}"
git config user.avatar "data:image/png;base64,${AVATAR_BASE64}"
git config user.name "${NAME}"
git config user.email "${EMAIL}"
git remote add publisher "${remote_repo}"
git show-ref # Useful for debugging
git branch --verbose

$(rm favicon.ico)
```

Comment: `git config user.avatar` Where from have you got the idea? Any docs? "*Is the only possible solution to use gravatar?*" No, you can upload a picture; see https://docs.github.com/en/account-and-profile/setting-up-and-managing-your-github-profile/customizing-your-profile/personalizing-your-profile#changing-your-profile-picture

Comment: @phd: I asked gpt. ;)
So I can't do anything.

Comment: Git != GitHub. Git doesn't care about user accounts or user avatars. If you want to set a GitHub avatar, head over to GitHub (or Gravatar) and upload one.

Comment: @knittl: But it seems like the avatar thing doesn't work on github either. :(

Comment: @Paul what do you mean? Did you follow [the instructions](https://docs.github.com/en/account-and-profile/setting-up-and-managing-your-github-profile/customizing-your-profile/personalizing-your-profile) and set your profile picture?

Comment: @knittl: It's not my profile, but a bot, more correctly an action that is passed off as a bot with its own specific avatar.

Comment: @Paul then set the profile picture in the bot's profile. Git != GitHub – Git doesn't know anything about GitHub profiles, profile pictures, or avatars.

Answer (score 1):

`user.avatar` is not a Git config option. Classic LLM hallucination.

There is no API for setting a GitHub profile picture. You can find a discussion on this at https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/65206.